# SQL group by 1 column but include TOP 1 of other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I am trying to build a SQL query where I group by 1 column, but then also include the values of other columns from an arbitrary record in each group. So, something like

```
SELECT BoxNo 
FROM MuffinData 
WHERE FrostingTimeApplied >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY BoxNo
```

but including some value from columns `MuffinType`, `FrostingType` in the result (I know that there will be only 1 value of `MuffinType` and `FrostingType` per box.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an aggregate function for each column selected that is not present in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT BoxNo, MAX(MuffinType) AS  MuffinType, MAX(FrostingType) AS FrostingType
FROM MuffinData 
WHERE FrostingTimeApplied >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY BoxNo
```

If there is only 1 value of `MuffinType` and `FrostingType` per box, then these unique values per box no are going to be selected in the above query.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that there will be only 1 value of MuffinType and FrostingType
>   per box

If that's indeed the case, a simple DISTINCT should do the trick, like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BoxNo, MuffinType, FrostingType
FROM MuffinData 
WHERE FrostingTimeApplied >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE());
```

If that's not the case, you're dealing with a problem known generally as the *Top N per group* problem. You can find coverage of the problem and suggested solutions [here](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2314819&seqNum=4).

Cheers,
Itzik

Answer (score 0):

If you're grouping by anything, then the only way to do this in a single statement (that I'm aware of) is to have the other columns you're returning be the result of an aggregate function.  Aggregate functions are anything that take multiple values but return you a single result like: SUM, MAX, MIN, COUNT, etc...

```
SELECT BoxNo, COUNT(MuffinData.ID), MAX(FrostingType.FlavorID) FROM MuffinData, FrostingType etc...
```

You might have to adjust your WHERE logic or have another data source in your FROM list (subquery).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE and join back to the original table to get the fields you want. In this case,

```
WITH BoxGroup AS (SELECT BoxNo FROM MuffinData WHERE FrostingTimeApplied >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) GROUP BY BoxNo) SELECT md.BoxNo,md.MuffinType,md.FrostingType FROM MuffinData md INNER JOIN BoxGroup bg ON bg.BoxNo = md.BoxNo
```